# Getting the max of a property using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to rewrite the below code using the Stream library (`allPeople` is a `List<Person>`).

```
int maxYear = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
Person oldest = null;
for (Person p : allPeople) {
    if (p.getDateOfDeath() > maxYear) {
        oldest = p;
        maxYear = p.getDateOfDeath();
    }
}
```

I am trying to find the oldest person in a list of people (assuming there is no Age property on the Person object, it's just an example).

How can I rewrite this using Java 8?

Comment: Wouldn't finding the one with the highest date of death just find the one who died most recently, not the oldest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Person oldest = allPeople.stream().max(comparingInt(Person::getDateOfDeath)).orElse(null);
```

This code creates a Stream of Person and selects the max element when comparing the date of death. This is done by using [`Comparator.comparingInt(keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) with the key extractor being a method-reference to the date of death of the person.

If the list was empty, `null` is returned.

As noted in the comments, you could also use [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-java.util.Comparator-) but note that this throws a [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) if the list is empty so we need to take care of that before:

```
Person oldest = allPeople.isEmpty() ? null : Collections.max(allPeople, comparingInt(Person::getDateOfDeath));
```